# Get Location Over IP in PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, location, ip

Before marking this question as duplicate please actually read my request.

I have checked out several geoip scripts. Some work, some don't. But what I have not found is a geoip script which works over a simple database. I don't want to install anything!! Just raw data which tell the php code which ip belongs to which latitude and longitude. Any suggestions? And if yes please don't only provide an api, but at least a tutorial which shows me how to implement this.

And if you have already checked some responses on stackoverflow you will note that they are outdated. A lot of pages don't exist anymore.

I have tried out maxmind and some other apis but they always need an external script.

Comment: It's not duplicate.  It's **too broad**.  What have you tried? What resources have you researched?  And, *recommendations for a libary* are not a good fit either...

Comment: maxmind is quite popular i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually what I was searching for: http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-use-the-free-geoip-database-from-maxmind-in-php/